# Ist die Form »mein Gutster« akzeptabel im Hochdeutschen?

Tags: word-usage, dialect

Ist die Form ***mein Gutster*** als liebevolle Anrede akzeptabel und korrekt auch in der hochdeutschen Sprache? Hier in Dresden habe ich das ziemlich oft so gehört.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nein, diese Anrede ist im Standarddeutschen nicht akzeptiert. Natürlich ist sie möglich, natürlich wird sie verstanden, aber verwendet wird sie in der Regel nicht.

Laut den Kommentaren unter der Frage scheint sie aus dem Sächsischen und verwandten Dialekten zu stammen. In allen Dialekten, die ich besser kenne (Süden bis Südwesten Deutschlands), ist sie mir noch nicht begegnet.

Answer (score 4):

Im Standarddeutschen gibt es das nicht.

Hier, im sächsischen Raum, wird "Gutster" und "Gutste" oft für "Freund" bzw. "Freundin" im Sinne eines Partnerschaftsverhältnisses verwendet. Aber nicht ausschließlich (siehe auch [Antwort von user53860](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71455/31962)).

Für die freundschaftliche Anrede wird eher "mein Guter" verwendet.

Comment: Passt nicht auf die Situationen, wo ich es gehört hatte - ich halte diese Antwort für tendenziell falsch.

Comment: @RalfJoerres kann auch immer die ironische Verwendung sein, also die Bedeutung umkehren.

Answer (score 3):

### Nein.

Das ist in einem standarddeutschen Kontext nicht akzeptabel.

Das zweisilbige Wort »**Gutster**« (ohne e nach *gut*) habe ich noch nie gehört. Für meine Ohren klingt es schlichtweg falsch. Den anderen Antworten und Kommentaren zufolge scheint es Regionen in Deutschland zu geben, in denen dieses Wort zur Umgangssprache oder zu einem Dialekt gehören.

Das dreisilbige Wort »**Gutester**« (mit e nach *gut*) wird dort wo ich lebe (Wien) zwar auch nicht verwendet, aber ich glaube es in alten österreichisch-deutschen Film-Komödien (mit Peter Alexander, Gunther Philipp, Theo Lingen usw.) in der Floskel »mein Gutester« bereits als scherzhafte Verballhornung von »mein Bester« gehört zu haben.

Aber nachdem Verballhornungen per Definition kein Standard-Deutsch sind, haben sie in einem rein standardsprachlichen Kontext nichts zu suchen.

---

Exkurs zu »**Hochdeutsch**«:
Der Begriff »Hochdeutsch« ist nicht klar definiert. Er bezeichnet ...

- (a) ... den Gegensatz zu Niederdeutsch. Hochdeutsch ist eine Gruppe von Dialekten, die im Süden (oben, auf den Bergen), gesprochen werden, und sich in vielen Eigenschaften vom Niederdeutsch (unten, im nördlichen Flachland) unterscheidet. Die geographische Grenze zwischen den beiden Dialekt-Familien stellt die Benrather Linie dar, die man auch die Appel/Apfel-Linie nennt.
- (b) ... den Gegensatz zu allen deutschen Dialekten. Hochdeutsch ist die standardisierte Dachsprache, die an Schulen gelehrt wird, und für die es - im Gegensatz zu Dialekten - verbindliche Regeln gibt.

Um eine Verwechslung zu vermeiden, sollte man im Fall von (a) ausdrücklich von hochdeutschen Dialekten und im Fall von (b) besser von Standarddeutsch sprechen.

Comment: Es ist keine Verballhornung von *Bester*, meine ich. Könnte einen Gutshalter oder ähnliches bezeichnen, vgl En *Trickster, Prankster, Lobster* ...

Comment: @vectory: Nein, und zwar aus zwei Gründen: 1. Das Wort *»Gutshalter«* kommt im deutschen Wortschatz nicht vor. 2. Selbst wenn es dieses Wort gäbe: Es gibt im Deutschen keinen Mechanismus, der *»Gutshalter«* zu *»Gutster«* oder *»Gutester«* verkürzen würde.

Comment: Und nocheinmal zu *»Gutster«*: In deutschen Wörtern kann vor *»ster«* nur ein Vokal (*Laster, Schwester, Geschwister, Kloster, Muster, Schweinemäster, Tröster, Küster, ...*) oder einer der folgenden sonoren Konsonanten stehen: L (*Polster*), M (*Hamster*), N (*Fenster*), R (*Förster*) oder der Digraph CH (*Nächster*). Wörter, in denen etwas anders davor steht (*Hipster, Youngster, Gangster, Dragster, Trickster) sind Fremdwörter, die aus der englischen Sprache importiert wurden.

Comment: dann habe ich es wohl eben erst analog zu *Haushalter* gebildet; Ich habe auch nicht die Behauptung aufgestellt, das sei die Vorlage für *Gutster* gewesen, denn es war nur ein wagemutiger, beispielhafter Deutungsversuch. Der Regelmäßigkeit der Bildungsregel wäre recht einfach beizukommen, wenn ein zusammengezogenes e eingefügt wird, *mein Gutester, Gut'ster*. Dass es als Verballhornung von "Bester" aufgefasst wird und wohl auch schon länger derart verwendet worden sein mag, wollte ich übrigens gar nicht bestritten haben.

Comment: Was ist ein "standarddeutscher Kontext"? Vollzieht sich z.B. Genderdeutsch in einem standarddeutschen Kontext?

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Standarddeutsch ist jenes Deutsch, das durch Vokabular, sowie durch Grammatik-, Rechtschreib-, Zeichensetzungs- und Ausspracheregeln standardisiert ist. Das ist jenes Deutsch, in dem Gesetze, Verordnungen, Bescheide usw. verfasst werden, es ist jenes Deutsch, das Grundlage der Benotung im Deutschunterricht ist und es ist jenes Deutsch, das Nachrichtensprecher im Fernsehen und im Radio sprechen. Weil Deutschland, Österreich und die Schweiz die deutsche Sprache unterschiedlich standardisiert haben, gibt es auch drei verschiedene Varietäten des Standarddeutsch. Wenn etwas nicht ...

Comment: ... dem explizit geregelten Standard entspricht, ist es Umgangssprache oder Dialekt. Dafür gibt es natürlich auch Regeln, die werden aber nicht explizit ausformuliert und in Schulbücher gedruckt. Beim Versuch, die gesellschaftliche Gleichberechtigung der Geschlechter auch in der deutschen Sprache abzubilden, werden dem Standard zusätzliche explizite Regeln hinzugefügt. Es ist also eine Erweiterung des Standards, die zumindest auf der technischen Ebene mit zusätzlichen Regeln vergleichbar ist, die Zeitungs- und Zeitschriftenredaktionen ihren Autoren auferlegen.

Answer (score 3):

Mein Gutster, meine Gutste ist eine am oberen Rand angesiedelte Respektformel im Sächsischen und anderen mitteldeutschen Dialekten. Sie kann aber auch erzieherisch / satirisch gemeint sein. Normalerweise sagt man es zu guten Freunden, die einem geholfen haben, denen man vertraut, die mit einem gleicher Meinung sind. Es wird praktisch NIEMALS in partnerschaftlichen Verhältnissen verwendet. Da gibt es Begriffe wie meene Liebschte, Die Frau, die Olle. Oder meen Liebschter, mein Liebster, etc. ... Sehr verwandt ist die Anrede mit "meiner Einer" und "meine Eine", was den sächsischen Begriff "Gutste(r) spätestens nördlich von Halle ersetzt.

Comment: Gute geschichtliche/herkömmliche Erklärung der Begrüssung, beantwortet jedoch die Frage, ob es in der Deutschen Sprache verwendet/akzeptiert wird, nicht wirklich…

Comment: Ich hatte mich in meiner Antwort etwas ungeschickt ausgedrückt. Es stimmt, dass es nicht **nur** für den Partner verwendet wird. Aber zu sagen, dass es "NIEMALS" dafür verwendet wird, ist genau das andere falsche Extrem. Ich bin hier geboren, lebe hier seit Jahrzehnten und habe es so schon oft gehört. Ich habe mir das nicht ausgedacht. So wie die Sprache lebt, verändern sich auch oft die Verwendungszwecke von Begriffen ;)

Answer (score 2):

"Mein Gutster" ist im Hochdeutschen nicht akzeptabel. Wie die bisher vorliegenden Antworten und Kommentare erläutern, wird die Anrede nur im Sächsischen verwendet. Im Hochdeutschen kann man korrekt "mein Bester" sagen.

Unklar beibt, ob *Gutster* oder *Gutester* ein fehlerhaft gebildeter Superlativ ist oder ob es sich um eine absichtlich geprägte ironisierende Form handelt.

Die fehlerhafte Superlativform "gutest" wird gelegentlich auch außerhalb Sachsens verwendet. Bespiele:

[1.](https://www.wein-konzept.de/bodo-bach-der-guteste-jubilaeumscuvee-dackermann) Zu seinem 20jährigen Bühnenjubiläum hat Bodo Bach ein Programm aus zwei Jahrzehnten unter dem Namen "Das Guteste aus 20 Jahren" zusammengestellt.

[2.](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/tv/moral-talk-bei-anne-will-die-guteste-der-guten-a-769302.html) Moral-Talk bei "Anne Will" - Die Guteste der Guten [...] Zuvorderst Margot Käßmann persönlich, "Mutter aller Rücktritte" (Will), Guteste unter den Gutmenschen und lebensweise Lesereise-Liturgin.

[3.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx2ln0I3X5E) Der Guteste · Fler feat. G-Hot. Aus dem Songtext: Wir sind die Echtesten im Rapgeschäft Boy Fler ist der Guteste, G-hot ist der Guteste

In den beiden ersten Beispielen ist die ironisierende Absicht erkennbar. Im Rap-Song könnte es eine spezieller Szenen-Slang sein.

Answer (score -2):

Hochdeutsch ist ein Formalismus, die Anrede ist aber Informell, also stellt sich die Frage eigentlich überhaupt nicht. Die Bildungsregel für Steigerungsformen ist prinzipiel hochdeutsch und die Bildung als solche auch klar verständlich. Zwar wird die Steigerungsform von *gut* regelmäßig *besser* sein. Das lässt den Schluss zu, dass es sich bei *Gutster* nicht um eine Steigerung handelt.

- Vergleiche Eng *trickster* und weitere

  ****-ster ist ein altgermanisches Agens-Suffix***, Genaueres ungeklärt